# Are there ways by which we can improve the performance of a React App when it has 2 awaits in the useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance

#### Goal -

I want the application to be fast. Unfortunately, it takes about 11 seconds for the app to refresh. But I don't want any component of my app to get removed from the app.

#### What I have tried -

Well, I did some research and according to me it happened because of a table I put in the application. When I removed the table and then tried refreshing the page, it refreshed fast but when I put the table back, it took a lot of time to refresh.

#### My `App.jsx` -

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Navigationbar from "./components/Navigation";

import { Grid } from "./components/Layout";
import CaseType from "./components/CaseType";
import CasesTable from "./components/CasesTable";

import { sortData } from "./utils/utils";

import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

const App = () => {
    const [confirmedState, setConfirmedState] = useState({
        addedTxt: 1111,
        presentTxt: 1111,
    });

    const [activeState, setActiveState] = useState({
        addedTxt: 1111,
        presentTxt: 1111,
    });

    const [recoveredState, setRecoveredState] = useState({
        addedTxt: 1111,
        presentTxt: 1111,
    });

    const [deceasedState, setDeceasedState] = useState({
        addedTxt: 1111,
        presentTxt: 1111,
    });

    const [countryTableData, setCountryTableData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const getDataFromApi = async () => {
            const responseForCountriesData = await fetch(
                "https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/countries"
            );
            const responseForCategories = await fetch(
                "https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/all"
            );

            const dataForCountriesData = await responseForCountriesData.json();
            const dataForCategories = await responseForCategories.json();

            let sortedData = sortData(dataForCountriesData);

            setConfirmedState({
                addedTxt: dataForCategories.todayCases,
                presentTxt: dataForCategories.deaths,
            });
            setActiveState({
                addedTxt: `-`,
                presentTxt: dataForCategories.active,
            });
            setRecoveredState({
                addedTxt: dataForCategories.todayRecovered,
                presentTxt: dataForCategories.recovered,
            });
            setDeceasedState({
                addedTxt: dataForCategories.todayDeaths,
                presentTxt: dataForCategories.deaths,
            });
            setCountryTableData(sortedData);
        };

        getDataFromApi();
    });

    return (
        <>
            <Navigationbar title="Covid-19 Tracker" />

            {/* routes (react-router)*/}
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" exact>
                    <div className="home">
                        <Grid columns={2}>
                            <section className="left">
                                <p style={{ color: "red" }}>Worldwide-</p>

                                <Grid columns={4}>
                                    <CaseType
                                        type="Confirmed"
                                        added={`+${confirmedState.addedTxt}`}
                                        present={confirmedState.presentTxt}
                                        background="rgba(247, 165, 165, 0.30)"
                                        textColor="red"
                                    />
                                    <CaseType
                                        type="Active"
                                        added={`${activeState.addedTxt}`}
                                        present={activeState.presentTxt}
                                        background="rgba(46, 123, 255, 0.30)"
                                        textColor="blue"
                                    />
                                    <CaseType
                                        type="Recovered"
                                        added={`+${recoveredState.addedTxt}`}
                                        present={recoveredState.presentTxt}
                                        background="rgba(92, 252, 84, 0.30)"
                                        textColor="green"
                                    />
                                    <CaseType
                                        type="Deceased"
                                        added={`+${deceasedState.addedTxt}`}
                                        present={deceasedState.presentTxt}
                                        background="rgba(193, 193, 193, 0.30)"
                                        textColor="gray"
                                    />
                                </Grid>
                            </section>
                            <section className="right">
                                <CasesTable data={countryTableData} />
                            </section>
                        </Grid>
                    </div>
                </Route>

                <Route path="/contribute" exact>
                    <h1>contribute screen</h1>
                </Route>

                <Route path="/info" exact>
                    <h1>info screen</h1>
                </Route>
            </Switch>
        </>
    );
};

export default App;
```

#### My `CasesTable.jsx` -

```
import React from "react";
import { Table } from "react-bootstrap";

const CasesTable = ({ data }) => {
    return (
        <>
            <p style={{ color: "red" }}>
                Click on the rows to copy the details 
            </p>
            <div
                className="table_div"
                style={{ height: "80vh", overflow: "scroll" }}
            >
                <Table
                    striped
                    bordered
                    variant="dark"
                    className="table"
                    style={{ maxHeight: "90vh", overflow: "scroll" }}
                >
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Country</th>
                            <th>Cases</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {data.map((elem) => (
                            <tr
                                onClick={() => {
                                    navigator.clipboard.writeText(
                                        `Country: ${elem.country} Cases: ${elem.cases} `
                                    );
                                    alert(
                                        "Country and cases copied to clipboard"
                                    );
                                }}
                                key={elem.country}
                            >
                                <td>{elem.country}</td>
                                <td>{elem.cases}</td>
                            </tr>
                        ))}
                    </tbody>
                </Table>
            </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default CasesTable;
```

For reference, this is what my app looks like -

[image: reference]

Also, this problem started when I put the second `await` in the `App.jsx`'s `useEffect`.

So, can I get some tips on making my app fast?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `then` and `catch` instead of `await`. In this case, both requests will be launched at the same time. In your code, the second request is not sent until the first completes

Example:

```jsx
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/countries").then(async (r) => {
            const dataForCountriesData = await r.json();
            setCountryTableData(sortData(dataForCountriesData));
        });
        fetch("https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/all").then(async (r) => {
            const dataForCategories = await r.json();
            setConfirmedState({
                addedTxt: dataForCategories.todayCases,
                presentTxt: dataForCategories.deaths,
            });
            setActiveState({
                addedTxt: `-`,
                presentTxt: dataForCategories.active,
            });
            setRecoveredState({
                addedTxt: dataForCategories.todayRecovered,
                presentTxt: dataForCategories.recovered,
            });
            setDeceasedState({
                addedTxt: dataForCategories.todayDeaths,
                presentTxt: dataForCategories.deaths,
            });
        });
    });
```

Also, if you need to update state frequently, you can combine multiple state constants into one. Then you can update the state with a **single call**

Comment: @Aviral some kind of error or keeps running slowly?

Comment: @Aviral my mistake, forgot to add await to json serialization. Changed answer.
I checked with a regular html table, it is filled very quickly